# Sending custom email template on woocommerce template while status changed

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have been trying to send html template that I had coded which is unrelated to the status emails from woocommerce. I have added an action hook when status for the order is changed to complete. However I do not want to just send the body and use the default template from woocommerce.

**example:**

```
function my_awesome_publication_notification($order_id, $checkout=null) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    if($order->status === 'completed' ) {
        // Create a mailer
        $mailer = $woocommerce->mailer();

        $message_body = __( 'Hello world!!!' );

        $message = $mailer->wrap_message(
        // Message head and message body.
        sprintf( __( 'Order %s received' ), $order->get_order_number() ), $message_body );


        // Cliente email, email subject and message.
        $mailer->send( $order->billing_email, sprintf( __( 'Order %s received' ), $order->get_order_number() ), $message );
    }

}
add_action("woocommerce_order_status_changed", "my_awesome_publication_notification");
```

Is there a way to fetch the custom template file name and sending it as a text/html email rather than creating a custom woocommerce template ? like in `message_body = _( 'custom template file ');` and fire it ?

Comment: I have the same issue.